# Laravel 5.6 Reverse HasManyThrough

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following table structure in my database:

### products

- id

### product_formats

- id
- product_id

### product_prices

- id
- product_format_id

When I'm trying to do `$this->format->product;` inside my `ProductPrice` class, I get an error:

> LogicException: App\ProductPrice::product must return a relationship instance.

When I perform a `dd` inside my function:

```
dd($this->format()->first()->product);
```

I get the instance of the product. However, removing the `dd` would still throw the exception.

Why am I getting the LogicException?

---

### ProductPrice

```
class ProductPrice extends Model
{
    public function format()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ProductFormat::class, 'product_format_id');
    }

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->format->product;
    }
}
```

### ProductFormat

```
class ProductFormat extends Model
{
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}
```

---

### Update

The result of `dd($this->format);` returns an instance of `ProductFormat`.

Comment: What's the result of `dd($this->format);`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir It returns the correct instance of `ProductFormat`.

Comment: And `$this->format->product()->first();`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir It returns the correct `Product` instance.

Comment: Why don't you actually use the hasManyThrough relation?

Comment: @Milkmannetje I will use the `HasManyThrough`. The `HasManyThrough` will allow me to get the `ProductPrices` via `Product` but not what I'm trying to do now.

Comment: What's the result of `dd($this->format->product())`;?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir It returns a `BelongsTo` relationship instance.

Comment: You'll have to debug `HasAttributes::getRelationshipFromMethod()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating the `HasAttributes::getRelationshipFromMethod()`, I've noticed that if the property does not exist in the `properties` attribute of the class, it will try to retrieve a relation, hence the error.

To fix it, I had to add the following to my class:

```
protected $attributes = ['product'];
```

Otherwise, I could call `product` as a function instead of attribute:

```
$price->product();
```